# Is it possible to keep same api urls when moving from monolith to micro service on Azure

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-web-app-service, microservices

I am breaking a monolith that is hosted as an app service on Azure. Application is made on .NET 4.8.

Is it possible to keep existing API calls in place, but redirect to a microservice instead of processing it by existing APP service?

Example:
Call POST
**some-url.azurewebsites.com/api/some-endpoint** should stay same, but getting processed by **my-microservice.net/api/some-endpoint**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

You can also use a [reverse proxy](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy) to redirect the API calls. This is a cheaper (cloud cost) way compared with the APIM solution, but it does require some dev efforts.

---

One of the ways to achieve this is to leverage [APIM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/api-management/#overview) in Azure, which acts as an API gateway and hides your microservices.

Assuming that you have designed two services,

- microservice A
- microservice B

Your existing API endpoints are,

1. some-url.azurewebsites.com/api/endpoint-1
2. some-url.azurewebsites.com/api/endpoint-2

You can now setup the existing APIs in the APIM as above, then create an API policy per endpoint to redirect calls to microservice A and microservice B,

1. some-url.azurewebsites.com/api/endpoint-1 -> service-A.azurewebsites.com/api/endpoint-1
2. some-url.azurewebsites.com/api/endpoint-2 -> service-B.azurewebsites.com/api/endpoint-2

[Azure App Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/application-gateway/#overview) can achieve the same result, but it could be expensive and hard to manage the redirects.

Comment: Thanks! But wow, thats one of the most expensive services i've seen on azure. Ill need to be able to process 2k request per second, and pricing for that is high high

Comment: Depending on your budget, APIM offers a consumption tier, i.e. it charges based on usage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/plan-manage-costs

Comment: @Djuro I just updated my answer. If cost is a big concern. Try a reverse proxy that is hosted by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Azure [API Management Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts). This service allows you to use different API backends from a single frontend with capabilities to rewrite requests.